# Problemas de ejecución de crontab en python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, crontab

No consigo ejecutar un *Script* de `crontab` en *Python3*.  He probado diversas fórmulas que he encontrado en foros pero sin éxito.  Para testear, he creado un `archivo.py` que simplemente ejecuta un impresión `"ok"`, pero no obtengo ningún resultado.

Algunos de los *Scripts* que no me han funcionado son:

```
python ./file.py
python /home/pi/file.py
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/file.py
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tienes `archivo.py` en algún lugar del `PATH` y que tiene `+x` en los permisos. Pones tu línea de `crontab`

```
* *  * * *   user   archivo.py --mi-flag --mi-otra-flag
```

Sustituye los `*` por los valores de tiempo que quieras y `user` por el usuario con el que se ejecuta el script.

Asegúrate también de tener el `#!` en la cabecera de `archivo.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Esto te debe funcionar.

Comment: Gracias,  he editado el archivo file.py para introducir #!/usr/bin/env python3 en la cabecera.  Por otro lado, el archivo tiene permisos -rwxr-xr-x.

Comment: El path al archivo es /home/pi.  Con el script * * * * * /usr/home/pi/file.py no consigo que funcione.